# Facebook AppRequests, Rails, Jquery, Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook

I'm a Rails newbie, learning how to send facebook application requests. I haven't found too much documentation on doing this in Rails, so I wanted ask if I'm on the right track or if there's a better way to do this.  Right now I'm looping through the recipient ids, and then storing the sender_id, recipient_id, and request_id in the database.  Here is what I have at this point:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          

$('#button').click(sendRequest);
    function sendRequest() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Check out this application!',
            title: 'Send your friends an application request',
        },
function (response) {
       if (response.request && response.to) {
          var request_ids = [];
             for(i=0; i<response.to.length; i++) 
            {
             var temp = response.to[i];
             var temptwo= response.request;
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:3000/fbusers",
                    data: {request : {
                                           recipient_id : temp, 
                                           sender_id: <%=@user.fb_uid%>, 
                                           request_id: temptwo}},
                 dataType: 'json', 
                     success: function(data) {
                        var obj= "hello there"    
                        alert(obj);         
                          },    
              });
            }
        } else {
           alert('canceled');
            }
        });
        return false;
        }
```

The controller just has this:

```
 def create
   User.create(params[:request] )
 end
```

At this point, my primary concerns are (1) whether this method is considered 'good practice', and (2) whether there is a faster (in terms of run-time), more efficient way to write this.  I mostly followed this tutorial (with a few changes), which was written for php:

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this, or if I'm on the right track.  Also, that tutorial combined all the recipients in one string, then 'exploded' them in mysql.  I was unclear what the point of this was, and if there was a downside to looping through the ajax post function.  Apologies for the long question, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem is what I recommend to you. Easy to use with Rails or Sinatra based applications.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I had already installed the gem and its been really useful for pulling data from fb's api, publishing to a stream, etc.  But I didn't see anything in the documentation that discussed how to create an app request through Koala.  I tried some code related to "put_connections()" etc, but nothing seemed clear.  If Koala would work for this, any advice/direction would be very much appreciated.  

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the tutorial combine all the recipients in one string is to be able to save all the recipients id (with your code you just save the id of the first recipient)!
The explosion is used to save each single recipients in one table raw, in this way you can after put false or true to the boolean parameter, and monitoring who accepted and who didn't your request without deleting them:)

You can also look at fb_graph gem, they added a partial support for app_request.

Hope this can help:)
Dinuz